What is the appropriate place for formatting methods in Laravel?
When developing an application with Laravel, I came across a question about the proper place (or indicated by the best practices) to put methods to format data.
As an example, I have a model Rubrica with fields fonte, despesa, etc.
The despesa field stores a 6-character string and the fonte field stores a 5-character string.
It turns out that for viewing on views, I wish you despesa is in a.b.cd.ee format and fonte is in ABC.de format.
The doubt I have is, the correct thing is to call formatting functions, for example fmt_despesa() and fmt_fonte () directly on the view (in this case, the functions would be defined as Helpers in /App/support/helper.php);
Or should create the static methods needed in the controller (RubricaController) by calling them directly on the view;
Or, you should put the formatting methods on the Rubrica model and call directly on the view in each recovered register of the model.
I really didn't find it in the documentation of the Laravel guidelines in this regard. I also found nothing relevant on the internet, including the OS.
I am grateful for the help and eventual feedback if the question is not properly written.

The answers to this question are going to be opinion based, but I think you'll find most developers agree that formatting belongs definitively in the V of MVC. Neither the controller nor the model should know anything about formatting. As such, I'd recommend creating your formatters as view helpers.

As per the comment of @Alex, this will be opinionated based on different factors.
If the format change is to be used multiple times across multiple sources (example: change carbon date format for different country formats), then it would make sense to use a helper function
<?php

namespace App\Helpers;

class CustomCarbonHelper
{
    public static function ChangeCarbonDateFormat($date)
    {
        ...
    }
}

Then use it as CustomCarbonHelper::ChangeCarbonDateFormat($date) or remove static and use is as a constructor in your class or do the new CustomCarbonHelper() way. Up to you.
But in your case, if you wish to only do so on 1 field at a time, then using Eloquent Mutators is your best choice.
<?php

namespace App\Models;

class Rubrica
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'fonte',
        'despesa',
    ];

    
    protected function fonte(): Attribute
    {
        return Attribute::make(
            get: fn (string $value) => $this->formatFonte($value),
        );
    }

    
    protected function despesa(): Attribute
    {
        return Attribute::make(
            get: fn (string $value) => $this->formatDespesa($value),
        );
    }

    public function formatFonte($value) {
        ...
    }

    public function formatDespesa($value) {
        ...
    }
}

The formatted value can be accessed normally:
use App\Models\Rubrica;
 
$rubrica = Rubrica::find(1);
 
$fonte = $rubrica->fonte;
$despesa = $rubrica->despesa;

Note: if your column is separated by _, then the attribute method will be camelCase:
is_example > isExample

this will be opinionated based on different factors. ...then please vote to close as "Off-topic: Opinion-based" instead of answering.
